# Sequence does skip numbers

Tags: postgresql

I have a sequence like this (in PostgreSQL 16.0):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.seq_1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 999999999
    START 1
    CACHE 1
    CYCLE;
```

and a table containing all `integers` from 0 to 1000000

When I do:

```
select *, nextval('seq_1') as n2 
from (
   select i,n1,n1-i as d, sum(i) over (order by i) as s
   from (
      select i,nextval('seq_1') as n1
      from integers
   )
)
where i=0 or i=1000000
```

the output is:

| i | n1 | d | s | n2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 46137349 | 46137349 | 0 | 50331653 |
| 1000000 | 47137349 | 46137349 | 500000500000 | 50331654 |

Why is the value for `n2` in the first row equal to 50331653?

I would have expected 47137349+1, I do not mind small gaps, but in this case the gap is 3194304  (`select 50331653 - 47137349`), which is big (or large?)

I have found:

- [postgres 9.0.4 sequence skipping numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356375/postgres-9-0-4-sequence-skipping-numbers), so I use `CACHE 1`

Comment: If you want to generate a series of something like consecutive integers, there's a [genrate_series()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) function for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  select i,nextval('seq_1') as n1
  from integers
```

You just created a gap which is as big as the number of rows in the table, so if you want to avoid creating large gaps, don't do what you just did.  How many times previous have you done this same maneuver?

Comment: About (`select 46137349/4194304;`)  11 times?    (BTW `select 2^22` = 4194304, do not not ask where this number is coming from .... )

Answer (score 2):

You are obviously familiar with the nature of a [`SEQUENCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) object - as reflected in your expected result.

#### Mystery? (Turns out, no.)

There is nothing in your question that would explain the difference. I recreated the test case and got `n2 = 47137350` as expected. Locally, as well as in this fiddle for Postgres 16:

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3Xc0oUs-)

| i | n1 | d | s | n2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 46137349 | 46137349 | 0 | 47137350 |
| 1000000 | 47137349 | 46137349 | 500000500000 | 47137351 |

```
  46137349  -- next sequence number (46137348 + 1)
+  1000001  -- number of rows in table (0-1000000)
= 47137350  -- next increment
```

`n2 = 50331653` in your result comes as a surprise.
The observed difference of 3194303 is odd on top, not being a plain multiple of 1000001.

If I start with the `SEQUENCE` at `seq_1 = 1`, the calculation becomes more obvious:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE seq_1 RESTART WITH 1;
```

| i | n1 | d | s | n2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1000002 |
| 1000000 | 1000001 | 1 | 500000500000 | 1000003 |

There must be something else going on in your DB. Either concurrent transactions drawing from the same sequence (seems very unlikely), or a trigger, or an odd query plan that results in burning more than 3x the sequence numbers. That would be triggered by something in your DB that's not reflected in the question (indexes, bloat, server configuration, column statistics, corruption, problematic behavior of your client, ...). Run `EXPLAIN` or `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and compare to the query plan in my fiddle. But I honestly can't think of a query plan that would do that.

**Turns out**, you just missed the much bigger number of rows in table `integers`, so mystery solved.

#### Query

That said, your query is probably a big waste. There are **much** cheaper ways than burning through a million sequence numbers. Like (exact equivalent):

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT nextval('seq_1') AS n1, sum(i) AS s
   FROM   generate_series (0, 1000000) i
   )
SELECT 0 AS i, n1, n1 AS d, 0 AS s, setval('seq_1', nextval('seq_1') + 1000000) AS n2
FROM   cte
UNION ALL
SELECT 100000, n1 + 100000, n1, s, nextval('seq_1')
FROM   cte;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MlQwYcJ3)

No `integers` table needed, either.

Probably, you actually do more than you have shown.
Probably, there is a cheaper way for that, too.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the "There is nothing in your question that would explain the difference" made me check how many records there are in the table `integers`, where i claim that there are 1000001 records, there are in  fact 4194304 records. A reproduction of the problem (I had) is: https://dbfiddle.uk/bVHp-Kqo, or a _solution_ would be: https://dbfiddle.uk/aOMTSDU5

Comment: Thank you for the edit, but I was not looking for a much cheaper way to do something equivalent.  The question is a simple reproduction of a real scenario. I faced in this reals scenario unexpected gaps, and the _real_ solution is that I do not have gaps, but that I did do a `NEXTVAL()`, without using this value.... (so the answer from @jjanes is more correct than yours.)